# xml complex nodes merging through xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, merge

I need to merge the two complex elements nodes through xslt, based on the attribute value i.e for eg when id=1 its respective name value elements need to be merged. so on for id=2, 3 ..etc

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xrefStore>
<xrefData>
    <entityData>
        <entry id="1">
            <keyValue name="A" value=" "/>
            <keyValue name="B" value=" "/>
            <keyValue name="C" value=" "/>
        </entry>
        <entry id="2">
            <keyValue name="A" value=" "/>
            <keyValue name="B" value=" "/>
            <keyValue name="c" value=" "/>
            <keyValue name="D" value=" "/>
            <keyValue name="E" value=" "/>
        </entry>
        <entry id="1">
            <keyValue name="D" value=" "/>
            <keyValue name="E" value=" "/>
        </entry>
    </xrefStore>
</xrefData>
```

The final output should be as below,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<set id="1">
    <nameValuePair>
        <name>A</name>
        <value> </value>
    </nameValuePair>
    <nameValuePair>
        <name>B</name>
        <value> </value>
    </nameValuePair>
    <nameValuePair>
        <name>C</name>
        <value> </value>
    </nameValuePair>
    <nameValuePair>
        <name>D</name>
        <value> </value>
    </nameValuePair>
    <nameValuePair>
        <name>E</name>
        <value> </value>
    </nameValuePair>
</set>
<set id="2">
    <nameValuePair>
        <name>A</name>
        <value> </value>
    </nameValuePair>
    <nameValuePair>
        <name>B</name>
        <value> </value>
    </nameValuePair>
    <nameValuePair>
        <name>C</name>
        <value> </value>
    </nameValuePair>
    <nameValuePair>
        <name>D</name>
        <value> </value>
    </nameValuePair>
    <nameValuePair>
        <name>E</name>
        <value> </value>
    </nameValuePair>
</set>
</root>
```

i have tried the below code, but it does not merge based on id.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="xrefStore/xrefData/entityData/entity/entry">
            <set >
                <xsl:attribute name="id">
                    <xsl:value-of select="current()/@id" />
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:for-each select="current()/keyValue">
                    <nameValuePair>
                        <name>
                            <xsl:value-of select="current()/@name" />
                        </name>
                        <value>
                            <xsl:value-of select="current()/@value" />
                        </value>
                    </nameValuePair>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </set>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

i found similar answer in here,
[Merge XML nodes using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966392/merge-xml-nodes-using-xslt)

but i did not understand the concept of their implementation.

Comment: The example is confusing: where does the `1` in `<value>1</value>` come from? Anyway, this looks like a grouping problem, so it's essential to know if you can use XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Its a typo Micheal, there is no value 1.. it is just an empty value. This grouping can be done using version 2 xslt is it?

Comment: It can be done in both XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0 - but the methods are different. -- Please correct your example and clarify what should happen when merging two nodes with different values.

Comment: I am not sure on how to edit the content to correct it, i tried. Where as for expected output, for each of entry i would need every keyValue grouped and obtain a unique entry with id's with merged keyValue.

Comment: That's not clear. Please provide an example. And state your processor's version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though this question is couple of months old, thought of posting an answer so that it could be useful for others who may happen to land on this question.

**XSLT 1.0 Solution**

A key needs to be declared which will be used for grouping of the identical nodes. In the sample, the grouping needs to be done on `id` attribute of the `<entry>` element.

```
<xsl:key name="kId" match="entry" use="@id" />
```

Looping needs to be done for all the `<entry>` nodes whose unique identifier (returned by the `generate-id()` function) matches to the unique identifier of the key.

```
<xsl:for-each select="entry[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kId', @id)[1])]">
```

Lastly looping through all the `<keyValue>` nodes within the grouped keys to get the desired result.

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('kId',@id)/keyValue">
```

The complete XSL using version `1.0` is as below.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- declare key to group nodes -->
    <xsl:key name="kId" match="entry" use="@id" />

    <xsl:template match="entityData">
        <root>
            <!-- loop through the grouped keys -->
            <xsl:for-each select="entry[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kId', @id)[1])]">
                <set>
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <!-- loop through the elements of the key -->
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('kId',@id)/keyValue">
                        <nameValuePair>
                            <name>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
                            </name>
                            <value>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@value" />
                            </value>
                        </nameValuePair>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </set>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>     
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSLT 2.0 Solution**

Version 2.0 provides an easier approach for `grouping` using the `<xsl:for-each-group>` feature. Below is the XSL.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="entityData">
        <root>
            <!-- loop through 'entry' groups grouped by 'id' attribute -->
            <xsl:for-each-group select="entry" group-by="@id">
                <set>
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">
                        <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <!-- loop through current group for all 'keyValue' elements -->
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()/keyValue">
                        <nameValuePair>
                            <name>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
                            </name>
                            <value>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@value" />
                            </value>
                        </nameValuePair>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </set>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </root> 
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Both the solutions transform the input XML into the desired output

```
<root>
   <set id="1">
      <nameValuePair>
         <name>A</name>
         <value> </value>
      </nameValuePair>
      <nameValuePair>
         <name>B</name>
         <value> </value>
      </nameValuePair>
      <nameValuePair>
         <name>C</name>
         <value> </value>
      </nameValuePair>
      <nameValuePair>
         <name>D</name>
         <value> </value>
      </nameValuePair>
      <nameValuePair>
         <name>E</name>
         <value> </value>
      </nameValuePair>
   </set>
   <set id="2">
      <nameValuePair>
         <name>A</name>
         <value> </value>
      </nameValuePair>
      <nameValuePair>
         <name>B</name>
         <value> </value>
      </nameValuePair>
      <nameValuePair>
         <name>c</name>
         <value> </value>
      </nameValuePair>
      <nameValuePair>
         <name>D</name>
         <value> </value>
      </nameValuePair>
      <nameValuePair>
         <name>E</name>
         <value> </value>
      </nameValuePair>
   </set>
</root>
```